# Stop listen changes to store in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using `react-redux` in my `react` app.

In my specific component I need to get `state` only once from store after that I don't care it's value changed or not. It's just for one component other than that I need to listen changes in other components.

**component_need_state_only_once.js**

```
function MyComponent() => {
    const isFav = useSelector(state => state.product.isFav);
}
```

Once component render I don't want to care `isFav` change or not. Right now whenever `isFav` change component rerender which I don't want.

In `flutter` this option is available.  `Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `useSelector(state => state.product.isFav);` returns a new value the component will re render. You can create a container for MyComponent that sets isFav on mount (like in Arnabs code) and renders MyComponent with this value. If MyComponent is pure then it won't re render.

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector } = Reselect;
const { produce } = immer;

const initialState = {
  product: { isFav: 0 },
};
//action types
const UP = 'UP';
//action creators
const up = () => ({
  type: UP,
});
const reducer = (state, { type }) => {
  if (type === UP) {
    return produce(state, (draft) => {
      draft.product.isFav = state.product.isFav + 1;
    });
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectProduct = (state) => state.product;
const selectIsFav = createSelector(
  [selectProduct],
  (product) => product.isFav
);
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
//pure component, only renders when props change
const MyComponent = React.memo(function MyComponent({
  isFav,
}) {
  console.log('in my component render');
  return <h3>in my component:{isFav}</h3>;
});
//container, only sets state after first render with value of isFav
function Container(props) {
  const isFav = useSelector(selectIsFav);
  const [state, setState] = React.useState();
  // deliberate missing dependency of effect, turn off linter for this line
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  React.useEffect(() => setState(isFav), []);
  return state !== undefined ? (
    <MyComponent {...props} isFav={state} />
  ) : null;
}

const App = () => {
  const isFav = useSelector(selectIsFav);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(up())}>
        {isFav}
      </button>
      <Container />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immer@7.0.5/dist/immer.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Flutter works with a different type of store (observables) than React (event store) so you can't just opt out of listening to changes when you use React-Redux `useSelector`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `useEffect` when first time your component is rendering.

```
function MyComponent() => {
    const [state,setState] = useState(null);
    const isFav = useSelector(state => state.product.isFav);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(state === null){
            setState(isFav)
        }
    },[])

}
```

In that case, the `useEffect` will call in `componentDidmount` and it will check if the state is **null**. If the state is null, it will update the state with `inFav` data and then it will not be called again as the value of the state is already set and `not null`

Comment: The component will still render when the value returned from `useSelector(state => state.product.isFav);` changes, the effect will run every time and not just on mount because you did not provide empty empty dependency and `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` for linter.